# Solving for $3 \times 3$ matrices

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus

For the real numbers $p$, $q$, $r$, $s$, $t$, $u$, $v$, $w$, $x$,
$\begin{vmatrix} p & q & r \\ s & t & u \\ v & w & x \end{vmatrix} = -3.$

$$Find \space \space \space \space \space 
\begin{vmatrix} p & 2q & 5r + 4p \\ s & 2t & 5u + 4s \\ v & 2w & 5x + 4v \end{vmatrix}.$$

For this problem, I have tried bashing, but there are way too many variables inside there.  Also, it is very tiresome to expand the below matrix.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint 1:* Adding a multiple of one column to another column does
not change the value of the determinant, therefore
$$
\begin{vmatrix} p & 2q & 5r + 4p \\ s & 2t & 5u + 4s \\ v & 2w & 5x + 4v \end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix} p & 2q & 5r  \\ s & 2t & 5u  \\ v & 2w & 5x \end{vmatrix}
$$

*Hint 2:* There is another rule about multiplying all entries
in one column with the same factor.

Comment: I have usually seen these rules stated with regards to rows, not colums. But then there's a result that lets you translate between rows and columns when dealing with determinants

Comment: The Leibniz definition would make it pretty clear that it makes no difference if you use rows or columns.